# How do I play a prerecorded audio using GSM Sim800a with ESP8266 and Arduino IDE

Tags: audio, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, sim800

I am writing a DTMF based code that whenever I call a specified person using my GSM Module i.e. SIM800A and ESP8266 (NodeMCU v2) using Arduino IDE, person will hear an audio file about the DTMF Tones available.

But  while searching the internet on this idea I got this command to play a prestored amr file in the GSM Module

> AT+CREC=4,"C:\User\9.amr",0,90

Please someone help me by either telling how I can upload the amr file to the internal memory of my GSM Module,

OR

How I can access the audio file from the internal memory of my ESP8266 and play it.

A small help from your busy schedule is also really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? All the information you are looking for on how to use the AT command can be find in the "SIM800 Series_AT Command Manual".  BTW, your question has nothing to do with Arduino, ESP8266 or nodemcu, so don't spam tags.

Comment: Thank you for answering but there is a command for sending the file but no clear way how to do it from my local disk to the memory of the GSM Module. There is only the command but where should I store the amr file (ie in which folder) so that it could be picked up and stored to the memory of the GSM Module??

Comment: GSM module don't interact with your memory on your PC, you either has a SD card or some memory chip as the FAT as part of your module subsystem.

Comment: Okay thankyou, can you send my some links for my help

Comment: The feature is rarely used and not available on all the modules. Giving that SIM800 is more than decade old, instead of relying on SIM800 to do the job of recording, it is better for ESP8266 to recording andstore the file as LittleFS/SPIFS, then send via SIM800 as UDP/TCP packet.

Comment: Okay Thank you for the advice, will contact you after working on it if I got struck